# NCLOB columns vs NVARCHAR in oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have to store variable length texts in an oracle table. The most of them will be less than 200 chars, but some of them ocasionally will have thousands of characters.

I'm tempted to define the column as `NCLOB`, as this datatype stores up to 4 GB, but I wonder what would be the problem in doing so as in the 98% of the times a `NVARCHAR` column would be enought.

- The values will not change frecuently once inserted.
- There will be hundred of thousands of records.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is `%2`, data is data, right? You have to store those minority data so you have to use `CLOB`.

Comment: You're right, but the alternative would be a more complex table structure. Maybe 1 NVARCHAR column and another NCLOB, or something like that. But if there's no performance problem using one only NCLOB column (there will be hundred of thousands of records) I'd go for the simpler way.

Comment: When you create an `NCLOB` field, db creates a `LOBINDEX` and stores the field-data in the `index`. If you create a `NVARCHAR` field db creates only table segment for storing field-data. If most of your queries are going to be `SELECT` queries, you should use `NCLOB` field because it is pre-indexed. But beware, your `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s will be slower than `NVARCHAR` solution. You can create a manual index on `NVARCHAR` too, but this may cost you nearly double size of the data. And as for the storage side using `NCLOB` is beneficial. But for `DML` speed, use `NVARCHAR` field.